# Routing all console traffic through SOCKS

Tags: unix, ssh, socks

I'm running a couple of bash scripts from the console on my local computer, they need to access the internet, and I would like them to appear as if they're running on a server I own, so I set up a SOCKS connection:

```
ssh -D 8123 -f -C -q -N user@IP
```

but then when I check my IP with

```
curl https://ipinfo.io/ip
```

my IP is still the same.

What should I do so that all the traffic and all the scripts I run in the console use the socks tunnel once it has been created?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
export http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:8123 https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:8123
```

after you set up your socks tunnel